# Using atof with a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

So imagine I am parsing a file, and I have a class Students.

```
    class Students{
          float grade; 
          string name;
     }
```

why can't I do this?

```
    Student *James; 
    James->grade = atof(line[0].c_str());
```

Assuming my lines are strings.

Thank you!

Comment: Might want to make the pointer point to something first.

Comment: Show your declaration of `line`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I am assigning a grade to the student. A grade gotten from a file.

Comment: What is the real question.  I can imagine you are parsing a file, and you have a class `Students`, and as long as you've initialized `James` to point to a structure, the assignment shown should work — both compile and succeed at runtime.  What is indicating to you that you can't do it?  If the compiler complains, we'd need to see more code. If the code crashes, it is probably because you did not initialize `James`.

Comment: Also, `grade` is private, because `Student` is a `class` and you have no access modifiers.

Answer (score 4):

As you've written it, `James` is only a pointer -- it doesn't point at an actual `Student` object (note that you've also mis-matched the spelling -- "Students" in one place and "Student" in the other). You probably want something like:

```
Student James;
James.grade = atof(line[0].c_str());
```

Assuming you're using a fairly recent compiler, you can do it a little more easily:

```
James.grade = std::stof(line[0]);
```

If you really insist on `James` being a pointer, you'll need to create a `Student` object for it to point at:

```
Student *James = new Student;
James->grade = std::stoi(line[0]);
```

Most of the time, I'd prefer to put this code into `operator>>` though. Assuming a line from the file is something like `grade name`, I'd do something like:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Student &s) { 
     is >> s.grade;
     std::getline(is, s.name);
     return is;
}
```

Then you'd read all of Jame's information like:

```
Student James;
infile >> James;
```

Comment: If I declare the string in this way > `std::string line ("...");`, can I just do it in in this way? > `std:atoi(line.c_str());`

Comment: @huahsin68: I'd generally advise that you avoid using atoi (at all).

Answer (score 0):

The way it is written the grade attribute of the Student class is private. You would need to make an accessor method or make the attribute public. I recommend the first choice. Once that is done you could use the following to accomplish your task.

```
James->GetGrade(atof(line[0].c_str()));
```